Does the measurement happen in the observed dimension or the entire spacetime?
Consider single particle double slit experiment, the interference happened in $xz$ plane while the particle traveled in $x$ direction, and the interference, dependent on if the observable $M_{xz}$ presented, showed up on a $z(y)$ plane for a fixed $x$.
However, consider a single particle interference through finite slits, where the slit has a $2$ dimensional geometry (in contrast to double slit where the geometry on the $y$ direction was ignored), for a simple case, make three round holes on the vertex of an equilateral triangle. In this case, the interference pattern is $2$D, where $y$ direction could not be ignored. However, what will happen if only $M_{xz}$ were presented, but not $M_{xy}$? If there is only $M_{xz}$, the particle position at $y$ were still not observed. Will the interference pattern still show up on the $y$ direction of the $zy$ plane?
Does the measurement happen in the observed dimension or the entire spacetime?

It doesn't matter what's presented. Only the nature of the irreversible interaction that could be used to detect the particle matters. If you have a planar detector, it interacts in 2D (actually 3D if you consider time) whether or not you fail to present any of the dimensions.

Then use multiple wavelets and measure the potential, or use electrons and then measure the photon interaction. Either, it can be done.

@ShoutOutAndCalculate What's "it"?
